# Format date to show Day (e.g. Friday) using fmt tag in JSTL

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jstl

I have a date object passed on to the JSP page as ${date}. I want to print the date in following format:

Last logged in on Friday, September 23, 2011 on 11:32 PM EDT.

I cant get the Friday part and the EDT part. All I am able to successfully print is:

Last logged in on September 23, 2011 on 11:32 PM.

What are the additional options I need to include for printing the Day and Timezone? Thanks in advance.

PS: I am using fmt tag in JSTL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the `java.util.SimpleDateFormat`.  That's the basis for the `<fmt>`

You sound like you want either a custom format or FULL.

Comment: I did not want a FULL format, but a custom one. I had an 'on' in between date and time. Also I want to print EDT and not EST. I could not figure out how to do it on JSP and also doing it on the server side and keeping JSP as much dumb as possible is my goal. So, I did it from the controller by formatting it over there and passing the date as a string to JSP. Thanks for the help anyway. I appreciate it.